# Why does "don't have a cow" mean "chill out" or "calm down" in American English?

Tags: expressions

I am just unable to understand why "don't have a cow" can mean "don't panic".

What is the origin of this expression?

What's more, If someone is getting flurried, can I say "he is having a cow"?

Comment: I'm moving this to ELU because etymology question are off-topic on ELL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"have" can mean "give birth to". (As in, "She's having a baby.")  Having a baby causes a lot of noise, excitement and distress.  So imagine the fuss over having a cow!

I don't think "he's having a cow" is commonly used. I've only heard it in the expression "don't have a cow".

Comment: And: 'If my mother finds out, she'll have a cow'

Comment: @Jim Good point. Yes, I recognise that usage.

Comment: In a movie, Sixteen Candles (1984): [quote](http://www.subzin.com/quotes/Sixteen+Candles/Everything%27s+fine.+Don%27t+have+a+cow), and then frequently in 'The Simpsons'